# Do the all points in subgroup of an elliptic curve with prime order have the same order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elliptic-curves, cyclic-groups

A subgroup $G$ of elliptic curve can constructed with point $P$ with order $q$ by $G=\langle P\rangle $.

Now, if $q$ is prime, do the all points in subgroup $G$ (except infinity point) have same order $q$?

Comment: That’s true in any group: a group of prime order $q$ has one element of order $1$ and all other elements of order $q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course. This is nothing to do with elliptic curves. All the elements of a group (or subgroup) have an order that divides the order of the group (or subgroup).